# Trigger jobs in github workflow based on the checklist in pull request template

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I want to trigger certain jobs on github action based on what is being checked off in the pull request template, is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible. You can write your own little script where you can check the checkboxes and you can call it in the GitHub action.

Comment: Is there an example of how this is done?

Comment: There is no example but you can start with [getting the pull request](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#pulls-get). There you can find the description in the `body`. And at the end you can check the boxes.